# Dynamic function call in Node (without frameworks)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

**Hello.**

2 weeks ago I started to study Node.
I decided to implement my server built on MVC as the training.
I used to do it with PHP.
I can not implement a function call, the name of which is calculated by the program.

File **router.js**

```
var maincontroller = require("../controllers/maincontroller");
var storecontroller = require("../controllers/storecontroller");
var additionalcontroller = require("../controllers/additionalcontroller");

module.exports = {
    findMainRoute: function (globalarray) {
    ... code        
                var nameOfController = temparray[0];
                var nameOfFunction = temparray[1];
                // var execFunction = nameOfController + '.' + nameOfFunction +'(globalarray);';
                // eval(execFunction);
        ... code
    }
}
```

In the file, the program calculates the name of the controller and the name of the function that the router needs to run. In the commented lines, calls this function with EVAL. This method works, but does not suit me.

At the moment when it works, one of the controllers will be called.
Controller **maincontroller.js**

```
module.exports = {
    processingMain: function (globalarray) {
    ... code
        globalarray.readFile = globalarray.mainDirectory + '/app/views/0000_main.html';
        globalarray.contentType = 'text/html';
    ... code
    }
}
```

If the call were not dynamic, I would write a call to the controller like this:

```
maincontroller.processingMain(globalarray);
```

Which JS / Node code should I write to replace eval with the PHP function analogue call_user_func_array?
For 3 days I tried 100 variants of applications Apply, Call, New Function. It seems that my knowledge of Js is too weak for such a task.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can always execute a method of an object via string:

```
let basicObject = {
  method: () => console.log('method was executed')
}

let methodName = 'method';

basicObject[methodName](); //prints "method was executed"
```

Maybe you can integrate that somewhere.